# Shuold I use not exists or join statement to filter out NULLs?

Tags: sql, database, join, null, exists

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  name 
        FROM    eotm_dyn d
        WHERE   d.employeeID = e.id
        )
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM employees a LEFT JOIN eotm_dyn b on (a.joinfield=b.joinfield) WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

Which is more efficient,some analysis?

Comment: depends on your RDBMS, your indexes, and the state of your statistics. Suggest you start by telling the none-omnipotent which RDBMS, and also running the explain plan for it...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the column values involved **can not be NULL** -

### MySQL:

`LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is **more efficient** than `NOT EXISTS` - read [this article for details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

### Oracle:

[They are equivalent](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/).

### SQL Server:

`NOT EXISTS` is **more efficient** than `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` - [read this article for details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

### Postgres:

Like Oracle, [they are equivalent](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/).

If you have trouble with the detail that the column values can not be null, yet use the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL - remember what a LEFT JOIN signifies.  [This link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I really think you should profile for such a question. Not only does it depend on the exact database product, but in theory it could also depend on the skew of your data.

However! By default I would say write the code that most clearly expresses your intent. You are after `employee` records without a matching `eotm_dyn`, so IMO the *clearest* code is `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. It probably won't matter, but I would use `SELECT 1` (not `SELECT name`), since the `name` is not important in the "without a matching `eotm_dyn` logic.

Once you have code that expresses what you intend and works, then look at optimising *based on profiling*.