# How can I make an SQL statement that finds unassociated records?

Tags: inner-join, exists, sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
tblCountry (countryID, countryCode)

tblProjectCountry(ProjectID, countryID)
```

The `tblCountry` table is a list of all countries with their codes and the `tblProjectCountry` table associates certain countries with certain projects. I need an SQL statement that gives me a list of the countries with their country code that do NOT have an associated record in the `tblProjectCountry` table. so far I got to here:

```
SELECT     tblCountry.countryID, tblCountry.countryCode
FROM         tblProjectCountry INNER JOIN
                      tblCountry ON tblProjectCountry.countryID = tblCountry.countryID
WHERE     (SELECT     COUNT(ProjectID)
                         FROM         tblProjectCountry 
                         WHERE     (ProjectID = 1) AND (countryID = tblCountry.countryID)) = 0
```

The above statement parses as correct but doesn't give the exact result I'm looking for. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT countryID, countryCode 
  FROM tblCountry 
  WHERE countryID NOT IN ( SELECT countryID FROM tblProjectCountry )
```

Comment: Although it works, I would say that this is not the most correct answer. Apparently, you should never use IN In SQL To JOIN with another table
according to http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2007/04/you-should-never-use-in-in-sql-to-join.html My answer shows how to use EXISTS instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT outerTbl.countryID, outerTbl.countryCode 
    FROM tblCountry AS outerTbl
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT countryID FROM tblProjectCountry WHERE countryID = outerTbl.countryID
        )
```

This uses what's called a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)

Note that I also make use of [the EXISTS keyword](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx) ([see also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx))

On SQL Server, NOT EXISTS is generally [thought to be more performant](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/). On other RDMS's [your mileage may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308885/shuold-i-use-not-exists-or-join-statement-to-filter-out-nulls/2308959#2308959).

Comment: Inner `SELECT countryID FROM ...` could be replaced with `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM...`. The proof of existence is good enough.

Comment: thanks, I never thought of that, although I always thought it was pointless to select something that is never 'used'

Answer (score 1):

There are, at least, two ways to find unassociated records.

## 1. Using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- each country only once
  tblCountry.countryID,
  tblCountry.tblCountry 
FROM
  tblCountry 
  LEFT JOIN
    tblProjectCountry
  ON
    tblProjectCountry.countryID = tblCountry.countryID
WHERE
  tblProjectCountry.ProjectID IS NULL -- get only records with no pair in projects table
ORDER BY
  tblCountry.countryID
```

As [erikkallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47161/erikkallen) mentioned this could **perform not well**.

## 2. Using `NOT EXISTS`

Various version of using `NOT EXISTS` or `IN` were suggested by [rohancragg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5351/rohancragg) and others:

```
SELECT
  tblCountry.countryID,
  tblCountry.tblCountry 
FROM
  tblCountry 
WHERE
  -- get only records with no pair in projects table
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tblProjectCountry WHERE tblProjectCountry.countryID = tblCountry.countryID) 
ORDER BY
  tblCountry.countryID
```

Depends on your DBMS and size of countries and projects tables both version could perform better.

In my test on MS SQL 2005 there was no significant difference between first and second query for table with ~250 countries and ~5000 *projects*. However on table with over 3M *projects* second version (using `NOT EXISTS`) performed much, much better.

So like always, it's worth to check both versions.

Comment: SQL server will not recognize this as an anti-join so it will be forced to do a left join + filter, which may or may not be better, but probably is a lot worse.

Comment: True. I've checked that on MS SQL 2005 with table with 253 countries JOIN-ed to tables with ~5k rows and over 3M rows. In case of table with over 3M rows `LEFT JOIN` was much slower. However on table with 5k rows the cost was similar to version with `NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM...)` suggested by [@rohancragg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490839/how-can-i-make-an-sql-statement-that-finds-unassociated-records/2490911#2490911).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ... WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ... )

Comment: apparently, you should never use IN In SQL To JOIN with another table
according to http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2007/04/you-should-never-use-in-in-sql-to-join.html

Comment: this is ridiculous, I shouldn't use some language feature because I might do a logical error?!

Comment: You should never do anything because I saw a blog post saying you shouldn't.