# Postgres query optmization

Tags: sql, optimization, postgresql, query-optimization

Hey guys, trying to optimize this query to solve a duplicate user issue:

```
SELECT userid, 'ismaster' AS name, 'false' AS propvalue FROM user 
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM userprop WHERE name = 'ismaster');
```

The problem is that the select after the NOT IN is 120.000 records and it's taking forever.

Using the explain prefix as suggested in the comments returns:

```
                                    QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
 Seq Scan on user  (cost=5559.38..122738966.99 rows=61597 width=8)
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Materialize  (cost=5559.38..7248.33 rows=121395 width=8)
           ->  Seq Scan on userprop  (cost=0.00..4962.99 rows=121395 width=8
)
                 Filter: ((name)::text = 'ismaster'::text)
(6 rows)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you please use psql to connect to your database, then issue your query, preceded by explain ("explain SELECT userid,..."), then add the output to your question?

Comment: "optimization" is misspelled in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put index on userid?

Or try another variation:

```
SELECT userid, 'ismaster' AS name, 'false' AS propvalue FROM user 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM userprop 
 WHERE userpop.userid = user.userid 
   AND name = 'ismaster');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the name column indexed? How selective is the name value?
Also anytime you want to have someone recommend changes to a query provide the query plan, even on what appears to be a simple query. That way we really know what the planner is doing.

Comment: Sorry man, this is the first time I hear about a "Query Plan" I'm gonna learn more about it now. Thanks for teaching me something new :P

Comment: Check this out for starters 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308885/shuold-i-use-not-exists-or-join-statement-to-filter-out-nulls/2308959#2308959), using a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` might be either faster or slower than `NOT EXISTS`, depending on the RDBMS, though they're equivalent on PostGres.

```
SELECT u.userid, 'ismaster' AS name, 'false' AS propvalue FROM user u
LEFT JOIN userprop up ON u.userid = up.userid AND up.name <> 'ismaster'
WHERE up.userid IS NULL
```